# Should the RL agent be trained in an environment with real-world data or with a synthetic model?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, generative-model, time-series, environment

I want to train a reinforcement learning agent in an environment with parameters (for example, the wind speed, sun irradiation, etc.) that change over time. I have recorded a limited amount of data for these time series.

Should the RL agent be trained in an environment, which replays the recorded time series over and over, or should I model the time series with a generative model first and train the agent in an environment with these synthetic time series?

On the one hand, I think the RL algorithm will perform better with the synthetic data, because there are more diverse trajectories. On the other hand, I don't *really* have more data, because it is modelled after the same data the RL algorithm could learn from in the first place.

Are there any papers that elaborate on this topic?